# Design Pattern for .Net data reader

Tags: .net, design-patterns

What do you think the "ideal" design pattern for reading a certain file type into my application.

I want to be able to reuse the code in various places, so clearly I want to have this in a separate dll, however although I have no problem passing a filename or stream into the code, what's the recommended design pattern for handling the read data.

Reading all the data into an array and passing this out is obviously not ideal from a memory management point of view, but the only other way I can think of doing it is by raising events when a record is read, however this doesn't feel "right" in that I would be worried that some of the events could go astray.

I'm sure there's a really slick way of doing this, but I can't for the life of me think of it.

Thanks

Comment: Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the format? If it is text, passing in a `TextReader` would be ideal; and for xml, an `XmlReader`. If it is arbitrary binary, pass in a `Stream`.

For large data, the ideal approach *where possible* is to read the data in a non-buffered way - i.e. don't load it all into memory. Iterator blocks can be useful here, for example here's a silly example that shows reading lines (but it could just as easily `yield return` objects built from data in a stream):

```
    public IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(TextReader source)
    {
        string s;
        while ((s = source.ReadLine()) != null)
            yield return s;
    }
```

obviously in the general case a lot more processing may be necessary per item!

The caller now has a lazily-spooling, non-buffered source of your data, for example:

```
using(var file = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    foreach(var customer in YourSpiffyParser(file))
        DoSomethingFun(customer);
}
```

And handling stream/textreader etc allows them to use it in a decorator chain with things other than files; network streams, in-memory streams, compression/crypto streams, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to define something so general. You would have to specify more what you really need, or the file type. Then you can have a look at the .NET Framework itself, there are a lot of "XXXReader" classes, for example:

- BinaryReader
- TextReader
- StreamReader
- StringReader
- XmlReader
- XmlTextReader
- IDataReader
- EventLogReader
- XamlReader
- EntityDataReader

And each one is really different from the others... Some are abstract, some aren't, etc...